# Determine if this is true or false

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

If U, V and W are vector spaces and U is a subspace of V, W is a subspace of V then W = U. True or false ?

I want to say that this is false because:

$ V = R^3  \\
U = R^3 (x >= 0)\\
W = R^3 (x <= 0)\\ 
\text{both U and W are subspaces of V but W != U.} \\\text{ Is this logic correct ? }$

Comment: Neither $U$ nor $W$ is a subspace of $W.$ A subspace must be a vector space but a vector space is a group under addition and $(1,0,0)$ has no inverse in $U.$. Likewise for $W$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your question has a simpler reformulation: A vector space $V$ does not have two distinct subspaces. If the dimension is 2 or more this is false: one can find two distinct lines passing though origin in the plane.

Comment: Also if the dimension is one, as there are the whole space and the trivial one...

Answer (score 1):

Of course not, but your examples do not work, as your choices of $U$ and $W$ are *not subspaces*.

A trivial counterexample is $U=V$, $W=0$. (of course in the case $V=0$ the statement is trivially true).